# What is wrong with this code? I need to convert string into float

Tags: c++, atof, type-conversion

What is wrong with this code? I need to convert string into float. m2 has an error in *m2.length*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float v2;
    char *m2 = "1 23 45 6";
    for (int i = 0; i < m2.length(); i++) //to convert every element in m2 into float
    {
        v2 = atof(&m2[i]);
    }
    printf("%.2f", v2);

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: _"What is wrong with this code?"_ - Le'ts see...`using namespace std`, `atof`, `printf`, `system`, and `m2.length()`.

Comment: `char*` doesn't provide a `length()` member function. You probably meant to use `std::string` instead, and the `size()` member function.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to achieve? Repeatedly assigning to `v2` inside a loop but then only printing `v2` once after the loop is finished does not sound very useful.

Comment: If you want to convert every element to a float, one float will not suffice to hold your results. Use `std::vector<float> values;` to store your floats.

Comment: @EzzEddinAbdullah I doubt your program really _works_ just by fixing my suggestions, there's a lot more problems, as the other commenters have mentioned.

Comment: @fredoverflow I need to convert each element in the array so that I can store them to make operations 
I already place *printf* inside the *for loop*

Comment: Plus, you can't just iterate down the array and convert each into a number using the very unsafe `atof`. You're completely ignoring the place value of each number. And, what do you want spaces to mean? Right now, `atof` will probably return a 0 on the spaces, which is almost definitely not what you want. The easiest way to convert a String to a number is to write a `areAllNumbers` function that checks if the string is entirely numeric, then uses a `stringstream` to convert it if it is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ string without using the pointer asterisk ** * ** 
and inside the loop to print all the element

Comment: @Carcigenicate I made spaces because I would like to do a program that takes a matrix from the user as the form of matlab in brackets separating each row with *;* like this: 
**[1 2;3 4;5 6]**
So after erasing semicolons and brackets. It puts such a string

I will try the function you wrote, though.

Comment: @EzzEddinAbdullah You need to include information like that, that completely changes your question. You aren't trying to convert a String to a float, you're trying to convert a space-delimited String into many floats. I don't think either of the answers address that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay, I just meant at first how to convert string into float
Is it the same with space-delimited String?

Comment: Kind of. The problem it introduces is you have to cut up the string before you can convert each number. I think @fredoverflow's answer actually addresses that. I'm not sure though, I've never used `stringstreams` exactly like that.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to convert each element in the array so that I can store them to make operations

Okay so how about you use a string stream to extract the numbers from the string into a vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "1 23 45 6";
    std::stringstream ss(input);
    std::istream_iterator<double> end;
    std::vector<double> output(std::istream_iterator<double>(ss), end);
}
```

Comment: So how can I print the *vector* ?

Comment: You have to iterate over and print each element. Use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are too may things wrong with your code to explain each and every point. That's how I would do it:

```
float v2;
std::istringstream iss("1 23 45 6");
while(iss >> v2) {
    std::cout << v2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this: 
*while(iss >> v2)*

Comment: @EzzEddinAbdullah It parses the input for the next number and assigns it to `v2`, whitespaces are skipped. If parsing failed or no more data is presen, the streams state will be false, and the loop ends.

Comment: What does ,exactly, this function do? 
Does it convert string into array? or just one element of the parsed input?

Comment: [Here's more in depth info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).

Answer (score 0):

**Step by step analysis, for learning from the errors:**

First there is no member function [`length()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) for an array of characters, so you should define `string m2="...";` in order for the code to compile.

Then unfortunately your code would print only one number:  the last.  Why ?  Because your `printf()` is outside the loop.

Once you've put it inside the loop, you'd have plenty of numbers, but more than you expect:
 * the first iteration, it'd start with "1 23 45 6"  => 1
 * the second with " 23 45 6" => 23
 * the third iteraton "23 45 6"  => 23 again! 
 * the fourth iteration "3 45 6"  => 3 (did you expect this ?)

So you'd have to jump from one number to the next.  So instead of incrementing, you coud search for the next space, with function **[`find_first_of()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m2.length(); i=m2.find_first_of(' ', i+1)) // jump to the next space
{
    v2 = atof(&m2[i]);
    printf("%.2f\n", v2);
}
```

Here the [online demo](http://ideone.com/K0FFQr).

**Real c++ alternatives:**

Have a look at **πάντα ῥεῖ** 's solution:  that's the way we do it in C++

Answer (score 0):

Use `string` instead of `char*`, to make things a little easier.

For converting a given string to a numerical value, either use `stringstream` or `atof()`.

Quick solution to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> myFloats;
    string m("1. 2.23 45 6456    72.8  46..");

    // First of parse given string and separate char groups that serve as a number
    // => only consider 0-9 and '.'
    if(m.size() == 0)
        return 1;

    string charGroup;
    for(int i=0; i<m.length(); i++)
    {
        if((isdigit(m.at(i)) || m.at(i) == '.'))
        {
            charGroup += m.at(i);
            if(i == m.length() - 1 && !charGroup.empty())
            {
                // in case given group is a numerical value
                myFloats.push_back((float) atof(charGroup.c_str()));

                // prepare for next group
                charGroup.clear();
            }
        }
        else if(!charGroup.empty())
        {
            if(m.at(i) == ' ')
            {
                // in case given group is a numerical value
                myFloats.push_back((float) atof(charGroup.c_str()));

                // prepare for next group
                charGroup.clear();
            }
            else charGroup.clear();
        }
    }

    // Print float values here
    if(!myFloats.empty())
    {
        cout << "Floats: ";
        for(int i=0; i<myFloats.size(); i++)
            cout << myFloats.at(i) << ", ";
    }

    getchar();
    return 0; 
}
```